# How to select text without the html code when web scraping in Python (2.7)?

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping

The below code returns the text including the html code. However, I need to retrieve the text only so that it can be loaded nicely into a pd.DataFrame. How do I 'strip' the text?

```
#importing packages
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

#url
url = "https://example.com/this_is_just_an_example"

#request to get text from url
r = requests.get(url).text

#create soup version of the text
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, features="lxml")

#create a list to store the text
MyHeadlines= []

#appended the text to list Names
for i in soup.find_all('h3', {'class': 'headline'}):
    MyHeadlines.append(str(i))
```

Comment: try MyHeadlines.append(i.text)

Comment: i.text further cleans my data; however, I still face unicode issues in the DataFrame.

Comment: Without knowing the url, there is not much I (nor anyone else) can do to help. There was no mention of unicode issues in the original question. You can update your post with the url if you would like.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with some simple regex:

```
import re
CLEAN_TEXT = re.sub('<[^<]+?>', '', YOUR_TEXT)
```

Enjoy!